# What's the difference between the meaning of import statement in Python and Java?

Tags: java, python

I am a Python programmer. And I begin to learn Java recently. I find Python and Java both use import to get in code from other files. Is there any difference between the exact meaning of these import in 2 languages?

Comment: just for clarification...The tag you used is reffering to sth else...

Comment: in Java you can either do `import package.*` or `import package.MyClass`while in Python you do `from package import *` or `from package import MyClass`

Answer (score 6):

Java import allows a shorthand referring for classes. This is different from some other languages. For instance in Python, the import keyword imports objects into the namespace of a script. In Java, the import keyword only saves typing by allowing to refer to types without specifying the full name.

In python

```
In [1]: import os.path

In [2]: path
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-e7fa32cb05ba> in <module>()
----> 1 path

NameError: name 'path' is not defined

In [3]: os.path
Out[3]: <module 'posixpath' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>
```

you can not just refer to path using "path", you have to use "os.path"

Answer (score 3):

There are subtle differences.

In Java, you can refer to an object in a package or class without any `import`.

You can do so by `new java.util.ArrayList()`.

OTOH, in Python, you always have to import the wanted module somehow: before you can use `sys.argv`, you have to `import sys`.

Both can be abbreviated: in Java, you do

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

...

... = new ArrayList();
```

in Python, you can do

```
from sys import argv
```

and then use it.

Both as well have a "catch-all" syntax:

- `import java.util.*;` in Java allows you to use several parts of the same package, and
- `from sys import *` is the (frowned upon) Python equivalent of it.

Answer (score 0):

Both are same.

Import keyword are used to import built-in and user defined package into your source file. So that your class can refer to a class that is in another package by directly using its name.

Answer (score 0):

It is the way you import the module in python..

```
from os import *
path
```